# Is there any specific template to write a discovery paper? How to write a paper then?

Tags: soft-question, education, research-level

I am really an enthusiast of physics! I like to write, read and even live with physics! but the question comes how could I express my researches? I am an amateur physicist but don't really know how to write a paper or if there is a specific template. If possible please attach a template in the answer also!

Comment: You may find https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/11989 and https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/19499 helpful

Comment: Have a look at the https://arxiv.org/ papers  of physics

Comment: If you need software recommendations, you might want to check out LaTeX (it is not an actual software)

Answer (score 3):

When I was in junior high school, I was assigned to write an editorial, and I had no idea how to begin.  My mother suggested that I start by reading some editorials.  She was very wise.